# 'Pipe not connected' to a Java Callable son

Tags: java, pipe, callable

I want a pipe for communication from father to a Callable in a thread pool. However the pipe appears as "not connected" from the very beginning. If I use a Runnable instead, the problem disappears...

I extracted a simplified example:

```
    public class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        PipedInputStream a = new PipedInputStream();
        // create a list of Callables (one element) and invoke them
        Son x=new Son(a);
        List<Callable<Object>> ls = new LinkedList<>(); ls.add(x); es.invokeAll(ls);
        // create a line oriented pipe
        PrintWriter toSon = 
                new PrintWriter(
                        new BufferedWriter(
                                new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        new PipedOutputStream(a))),true);
        //write anything
        toSon.println("blah blah blah");
        //here you can add a Thread.sleep, no change
        toSon.close();
    }
}
```

The son:

```
public class Son implements Callable<Object> {

    PipedInputStream x;

    public Son(PipedInputStream x) {
        this.x=x;
    }

    public Object call() {
        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new BufferedInputStream(x)));
        try {
            System.out.println(">"+b.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Here following is the stacktrace, that corresponds to the readln in the son:

```
java.io.IOException: Pipe not connected
at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:306)
at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:378)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at prova.Son.call(Son.java:23)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake, but I do not understand the symptom :-/

The mistake is that I forgot that "invokeAll" returns only when all threads are finished: so the "blah blah blah" is never sent, and this is not what I expected. But I do not understand why an exception is thrown in the Son.

The solution is simply to replace the line:

```
    List<Callable<Object>> ls = new LinkedList<>(); ls.add(x); es.invokeAll(ls);
```

with a plain

```
    es.submit(x);
```

or with an appropriate while loop to handle a collection of runnable, as it is in my real case (yet to try...).

The (wrong) answer of EJP gave me a relevant clue, since in that case there is no deceiving symptom, but just an unexpected result.

Comment: It's not wrong. You have to connect the pipe before  you use it. You weren't doing that, so you got the 'pipe not connected' error. QED

Comment: You can write to a *not yet* connected pipe: the content remains in the pipe. This is relevant in my real case, by the way. The example given works simply replacing the wrong "invokeAll" with "submit" (tested).

Answer (score 0):

Create the PipedOutputStream before you call invokeAll().